# How to inject data through awk from CSV to Redis

Tags: csv, awk, redis

I'm trying to inject data from csv file to Redis.

If I run the script in the terminal, I get a JSON format, but I do not know how to insert this data into Redis. I try using `SET` at the beginning and `| redis-cli --pipe` at the end.

It works on terminal:

```
awk -F, ' BEGIN { print "[" ; }  { print " {\n" "   \"typeDocument\" : \""   $1  "\",\n"  "   \"numberDocument\" : \""  $2 "\",\n"  "   \"phone\" : \""  $3  "\",\n"  "   \"state\" : \""  $4  "\"\n" " }" }   END { print "]" } ' data.csv #FUNCIONA
```

This does not work

```
awk -F, ' BEGIN { print "SET" "[ ; {\n" "   \"typeDocument\" : \""   $1  "\",\n"  "   \"numberDocument\" : \""  $2 "\",\n"  "   \"phone\" : \""  $3  "\",\n"  "   \"state\" : \""  $4  "\"\n" " }" }   END { print "]" } ' data.csv | redis-cli --pipe #NOFUNCIONA
```

Please help me

I hope that when inserting the data from the csv file in Redis, the fields will be correctly in JSON format.

Comment: HI, and welcome to SO. Not sure if it's a typo, you seems to have left the BEGIN section open (missing } ). Looks like when adding "SET" you might have broken the BEGIN section. Please confirm the code snippet is exactly what you are running.

What do you exactly mean with "not working"?

Comment: Please reformat/indent your `awk` code over multiple lines so it is readable without having to scroll right to read it. Use the `{}` tool on selected text to keep the correct formatting like `code/data/output/statusMsgs/errMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: What's in your CSV? Please add a few sample lines. What do you mean when you say you want to put a CSV into Redis? Do you mean you want it as a hash, a list, a set? What's JSON got to do with it? Please improve your question.

Comment: Not related but may be of interest: https://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/redis/redis.html

Answer (score 1):

Output of your command contain newline (`\n`) characters, as you both use it yourself and use multiple `print`s. If value for SET contain newline characters, you must comply with [String quoting and escaping](https://redis.io/docs/ui/cli/), which gives following example

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SET mykey "Hello\nWorld"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> GET mykey
Hello
World
```

Observe `"` delimiting value and that there are two characters: backslash and letter n rather than single newline character. You need also escape `"` same way to prevent them for being treated as delimiter. Consider that if you say have following JSON file

```
{"Able":1,
"Baker":2,
"Charlie":3}
```

then it should result in following SET command

```
SET mykey "{\"Able\":1,\n\"Baker\":2,\n\"Charlie\":3}"
```